# Multiple twitter users' feed on one site without reaching the rate limit

Tags: php, api, twitter, rate-limiting

I have a large number of twitter users I wish to sydicate onto a website using PHP and caching the tweets in MySQL. However I seem to be stumped by the rate-limit problem when ever I access the API. Every request I make to every user seems to count as a request, which stands to reason.

I notice other sites* doing this exact thing successfully. How are they getting around this, are they simply whitelisted, or is there a technique I'm missing?

*http://www.twackle.com/NFL/Aaron-Rodgers_1/tweets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [streaming API](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api) is what you are looking for, and more specifically, the [filter](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_methods#statuses-filter) method. Filter, at its least-privileged level, will allow you to follow 5,000 users in realtime, without them having to authorize your app, and you can track up to 400 keywords using this method as well.

Now, if you want historical tweets as well, you *will* have to pull those from the REST API (the streaming API's **[count](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_methods#count)** parameter doesn't really help here), but since you can only retrieve the last 3200 tweets for a user via the REST API, you can pretty much backfill all *available* tweet history with 16 calls to [statuses/user_timeline](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline) by passing in a **count** parameter value of 200 and paging accordingly.

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=barackobama&count=200&page=2
 http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=barackobama&count=200&page=3
 http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=barackobama&count=200&page=4

With your 350 calls per hour per single Twitter account, you could backfill approximately 22 full user timelines per hour.

On the implementation side, you'd probably be interested in [Phirehose](http://code.google.com/p/phirehose/), a streaming API client interface for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

try to auth first, before get the tweets. that should increase the rate limit

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly - I'd need every account to grant access via the app, I won't know the users to get this access. Imagine it like the link I sent - potentially hundreds of sports players. If I even attempt to grab their tweets once an hour, I'd go straight over the 150 rate limit?

Comment: Authenticating as a single user will allow you to get updates from any public account with with an increase from 150 unauthenticated requests/hour to 350 requests/hour.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method of combining multiple user_timelines is to [create a Twitter list](http://support.twitter.com/articles/76460-how-to-use-twitter-lists) and use [GET /:user/lists/:id/status](https://api.twitter.com/1/twitter/lists/team/statuses.json). That single API request will return the most recent tweets from all users on the list.